# Unable to connect to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongodb and querying data from it. Here is what I am doing:

In node js my db connection file is looks like this:

```
//Using mongodb drivers has to be installed using npm
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dburl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/meanhotel';

var _connection = null;

var open = function() {
MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {
if (err) {
console.log("DB connection failed",err);
return;
}else{
_connection = db;
console.log("DB connection open");
}
});
};

var get = function() {
return _connection;
};

module.exports = {
open : open,
get : get
};
```

And the node js code which I am using to query data from the database is like this:

```
var dbconn = require('../data/dbconnection.js');

var hotelData = require('../data/hotel-data.json');

module.exports.hotelsGetAll = function(req, res) {
//
var db = dbconn.get();
var collection = db.collection('hotels');
var docs=collection.find();

collection
.find()
.toArray(function(err,docs){
console.log("Found hotels",err);
res
.status(200)
.json(docs);
});
```

If I visit the URL

> http://localhost:3000/api/hotels

Nothing is coming out.

Also in terminal I am getting this output.

```
Found hotels { [MongoError: not authorized on meanhotel to execute command { find: "hotels", filter: {} }]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'not authorized on meanhotel to execute command { find: "hotels", filter: {} }',
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'not authorized on meanhotel to execute command { find: "hotels", filter: {} }',
code: 13,

codeName: 'Unauthorized' }
```

I am using this for launch the mongo shell:

```
mongo localhost:27017/admin -u user -p pass
```

Also if I want to dump data to the database I am using this.

```
sudo mongodump --db meantest -u user -p pass --authenticationDatabase
admin --gzip
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right URL format when MongoDB authentication is enabled is:

mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

For your case: mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/meanhotel?authSource=admin

Reference: [MongoClient or how to connect in a new and better way](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

> var dburl = mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/meanhotel;